# Issues configuring Firebase/Messaging for iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing a new app and I hit an issue configuring Firebase/Messaging for iOS. I doubled checked everything and the only clue I have is an error I get in the iOS log:

> [Firebase/Messaging][I-IID003014] Error while reading embedded mobileprovision Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 “The file \M-b\M^@\M^\embedded.mobileprovision\M-b\M^@\M^] couldn\M-b\M^@\M^Yt be opened because there is no such file.” UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F473238B-EA6D-46BD-8B37-39081C56E771/Dramler.app/embedded.mobileprovision, NSUnderlyingError=0x17024b3a0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 “No such file or directory”}}

More details:

- We use react-native and react-native-fcm
- Firebase/Messaging pod version: 3.16.0
- FirebaseMessaging pod version: 1.2.3
- FirebaseInstanceID pod version: 1.0.10
- iOS device version: 10.3
- The app is currently published only in TestFlight
- Strangely enough, everything works fine in Develoment

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few lost days, finally found the issue. The Firebase documentation is wrong in the section where it describes how to export APN certificate and upload it in the Firebase console. You have to export only the private key for Development but **you have to export the actual certificate for Production**.

There are several similar issues in StackOverflow. I sent feedback to Google to improve the documentation. Let's see.

Comment: This tuto explains it well https://sweetcode.io/setting-firebase-push-notification-existing-nativescript-angular/